# socket io receive message only at the end

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, websocket

I want to stream a video from a flask server to a webpage. For testing purpose I only send text strings. The problem is that the client only receives the packages at the end. I have to wait 30 seconds and then I get all the messages. When I am using a endless loop to stream then the client never receives a message.
This is my server code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send
from flask_cors import CORS
import cv2
import base64
import time
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'justasecretkeythatishouldputhere'

socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="http://localhost:3000", logger=True, engineio_logger=True)
CORS(app)

@socketio.on('connect')
def on_connect(auth):
    print("CONNECTED")

@socketio.on("live")
def live(test):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    counter  = 0
    for _ in range(30):
        counter += 1
        ret,frame = cap.read()
        retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        send(f"Hi, {counter}")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

And this is my client code:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
function App() {
  const [test, setText] = useState("test")
  useEffect(()=>{
    const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");
    console.log(socket)
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
      console.log(data)
      setText(data)
    });
    socket.emit('live', "data");
  },[])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {test}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using ASGI web server to host this app, probably eventlet?

Your main loop occupies resources for the whole time and `socketio` doesn't have time to send data through a websocket - that's why you receive all the messages at the end. Simple `time.sleep` don't release it.

Try replacing `time.sleep(1)` with `socketio.sleep(0)`.